# Text color with DrawText in vc++ mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, drawing, drawtext, gdi

I'm using DrawText to print a message in my application form. how can I change the text color to RGB(255,0,0) ?

Even a change in background will be usefull.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CDC::SetTextColor`, if memory serves.